# if $2^n - 1$ can be divided by $49$, find $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a task to find $n$ if $2^n-1$ can be divided by $49$

Can i use Fermat's formula:
$$2^{49-1}\equiv 1(\mod 49)$$

so $2^{48}-1$ can be divided by $49$
and will $48$ be the only answer?

Comment: $49$ is not a prime number, you can not apply little Fermat's theorem.

Comment: You need the smallest non-zero number $o$ with $2^o\equiv 1\mod 49$, which must be a divisor of $\phi(49)=42$ ($\phi(n)$ denotes the totient-function). Here, we have $o=21$, so $2^n-1$ is divisible by $49$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $21$.

Comment: Even, if you could apply Fermat's little theorem, you would have infinite many possible $n$